# $.post is not working sometime on base64 image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cordova, post

I'm encoding the image file to the base64 and posting to PHP on serverside but I encountered a problem that some of the image string is not posted to the serverside at all. I've checked through the problem and still couldn't figure out why. At first I thought it was about the length of the string since most of the unsuccessful case have the string with length of over 820,000 but some of it with the length of 1,000,000 can still be successfully posted.

The following is my JavaScript code

```
var sender = 1000006;
var receiver = 90002;
var direction = 'U';
var type = 'I';

var message = "base64imageData";

console.log(message.length);//I check the length from here

$.post('image_upload.php',
    {
        message: message,
        receiver: receiver,
        sender: sender,
        direction: direction,
        type: type
    },
    function (data) 
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

And this is the upload_image.php

```
<?php
$temp = $_POST["message"];
$sender = $_POST["sender"];
$receiver = $_POST["receiver"];
$direction = $_POST["direction"];
$type = $_POST["type"];

echo $sender;// To check if received anything
?>
```

Some image will just return nothing which means the php is not receiving the value from the js.

I'n not very familiar with $.post and would like to know the problem of my code and what the $.post will do if the parameters exceed the max_post_size, is it passing the incomplete value of not passing at all? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: The post request seems to be successful as it called success function everytime, in this case, is there still be a possibility post_size problem?

Comment: what's your POST limit set to in your PHP config

Comment: The max_post_size is set to 8MB

Comment: I think this should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639103/uploading-a-base64-encoded-image-to-php-server

Comment: @NishanthaKumara thanks for that but it doesn't seems like the solution as my code can successfully post images but not for all image

Comment: Php will give you a warning if you exceed the maximum post size. Did you try ` .fail() ` in connection with $.post to see if any errors occur?

Comment: @Xorifelse i don't get it, but it works for other file like text and voice and some images